# racket: add a number to each element of nested list

Tags: recursion, racket

I'm trying to write this function recursively.  Please let me know if there's a library function for this in Racket documentation.  Trying to add a number to every atomic element of a nested list.  I'm guaranteed the list is only 2-deep

```
(define (add_to_all x li) (cond
  ((number? li)                             (+ li x))
  ((and (=(len li)1) (number?(car li)))     (list (add_to_all x (car li))))
  ((=(len li)1)                             (add_to_all x (car li)))
  (else                                     (list (add_to_all x (car li)) `(,@(add_to_all x (cdr li)))))))
```

Example usage:

```
(define list_of_lists `((1 2 3)(4 5 6)))
(add_to_all 1 list_of_lists)
```

Bug: I'm getting too many nested lists at the end of my return value:

```
'((2 (3 (4))) (5 (6 (7))))
```

where it should be

```
'((2 3 4) (5 6 7))
```

I think the problem is in the last `else` condition block, but I'm not sure how to "unnest" that trailing part to get what I want

Answer (score 2):

Whether the list is 2-deep or N-deep, it doesn't really matter, the algorithm can be the same.

```scm
(define (add-to-all x xs)
  (cond ((null? xs)
         null)
        ((list? (car xs))
         (cons (add-to-all x (car xs))
               (add-to-all x (cdr xs))))
        (else
         (cons (+ x (car xs))
               (add-to-all x (cdr xs))))))

(add-to-all 10 '((1 2) (3 4) (5 (6 (7 8 9)))))
;; '((11 12) (13 14) (15 (16 (17 18 19))))
```

The procedure can be generalized to allow any operation to be performed on all atoms of a nested list

```scm
(define (map* f xs)
  (cond ((null? xs)
         null)
        ((list? (car xs))
         (cons (map* f (car xs))
               (map* f (cdr xs))))
        (else
         (cons (f (car xs))
               (map* f (cdr xs))))))

(define (add-to-all x xs)
  (map* (curry + x) xs))

(add-to-all 10 '((1 2) (3 4) (5 (6 (7 8 9)))))
;; '((11 12) (13 14) (15 (16 (17 18 19))))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a simpler way than recursion:

```
(define (add x li)
  (for/list ([e li]) (+ x e)))
(define (add_to_all x li)
  (map (lambda(sublist)(add x sublist))
    li))
```

Usage:

```
(add_to_all 1 '((1 2 3)(4 5 6)))
```

If someone knows a library function for this operation, please answer as well

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem can be generalized to "How do I map over nested lists?".

I am working off the assumption the procedure should also add numbers to top level elements, e.g.: `(add-to-all 1 '(1 2 (3 4) 5))` yields `'(2 3 (4 5) 6)`.

Here is a recursive solution based on the question:

```rkt
(define (add-to-all x li)
  (cond
    [(number? li) (+ li x)]
    [(list? li) (map (curry add-to-all x) li)]
    [else li]))
```

A more generalized solution:

```rkt
(define (map* proc ls)
  (for/list ([elem ls])
    (if (list? elem)
        (map* proc elem)
        (proc elem))))

(define (add-to-all x li)
  (define (proc e)
    (if (number? e)
        (+ x e)
        e))
  (map* proc li))
```

I didn't see a procedure like `map*` in the standard Racket library, but I only looked for several minutes :).

Comment: I did not know you could use brackets in a `cond` like that.  upvote from me :)